# Problems while installing libvirt-python on MacOS

Tags: linux, macos, installation, python, libvirt

I want to use libvirt library for installing a VM on a KVM. While installing libvirt library on Mac, I'm coming across an issue. I tried installing libvirt dependencies but to no use. Can you please help me with this.

```
(venv) Siddharaths-MacBook-Pro-2:Homework1 siddharathgupta$ pip install libvirt-python
Collecting libvirt-python
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/73/37/52c7076b1b44efe4157d0744be7be01df0c0942f44daba458a77a19f9f8d/libvirt-python-4.10.0.tar.gz
Building wheels for collected packages: libvirt-python
  Running setup.py bdist_wheel for libvirt-python ... error
  Complete output from command /Users/siddharathgupta/PycharmProjects/CSCI561/Homework1/venv/bin/python -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='/private/var/folders/qh/gdlxnjkx39g723d68_l5dzhc0000gn/T/pip-install-SwC4Jj/libvirt-python/setup.py';f=getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('\r\n', '\n');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, 'exec'))" bdist_wheel -d /private/var/folders/qh/gdlxnjkx39g723d68_l5dzhc0000gn/T/pip-wheel-WnOPln --python-tag cp27:
  running bdist_wheel
  running build
  Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
    File "/private/var/folders/qh/gdlxnjkx39g723d68_l5dzhc0000gn/T/pip-install-SwC4Jj/libvirt-python/setup.py", line 366, in <module>
      "Programming Language :: Python :: 3",
    File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/distutils/core.py", line 151, in setup
      dist.run_commands()
    File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/distutils/dist.py", line 953, in run_commands
      self.run_command(cmd)
    File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/distutils/dist.py", line 972, in run_command
      cmd_obj.run()
    File "/Users/siddharathgupta/PycharmProjects/CSCI561/Homework1/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/wheel/bdist_wheel.py", line 202, in run
      self.run_command('build')
    File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/distutils/cmd.py", line 326, in run_command
      self.distribution.run_command(command)
    File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/distutils/dist.py", line 972, in run_command
      cmd_obj.run()
    File "/private/var/folders/qh/gdlxnjkx39g723d68_l5dzhc0000gn/T/pip-install-SwC4Jj/libvirt-python/setup.py", line 147, in run
      check_minimum_libvirt_version()
    File "/private/var/folders/qh/gdlxnjkx39g723d68_l5dzhc0000gn/T/pip-install-SwC4Jj/libvirt-python/setup.py", line 40, in check_minimum_libvirt_version
      spawn([get_pkgcfg(),
    File "/private/var/folders/qh/gdlxnjkx39g723d68_l5dzhc0000gn/T/pip-install-SwC4Jj/libvirt-python/setup.py", line 36, in get_pkgcfg
      raise Exception("pkg-config binary is required to compile libvirt-python")
  Exception: pkg-config binary is required to compile libvirt-python

  ----------------------------------------
  Failed building wheel for libvirt-python
  Running setup.py clean for libvirt-python
Failed to build libvirt-python
Installing collected packages: libvirt-python
  Running setup.py install for libvirt-python ... error
    Complete output from command /Users/siddharathgupta/PycharmProjects/CSCI561/Homework1/venv/bin/python -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='/private/var/folders/qh/gdlxnjkx39g723d68_l5dzhc0000gn/T/pip-install-SwC4Jj/libvirt-python/setup.py';f=getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('\r\n', '\n');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, 'exec'))" install --record /private/var/folders/qh/gdlxnjkx39g723d68_l5dzhc0000gn/T/pip-record-4drvGZ/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile --install-headers /Users/siddharathgupta/PycharmProjects/CSCI561/Homework1/venv/include/site/python2.7/libvirt-python:
    running install
    running build
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
      File "/private/var/folders/qh/gdlxnjkx39g723d68_l5dzhc0000gn/T/pip-install-SwC4Jj/libvirt-python/setup.py", line 366, in <module>
        "Programming Language :: Python :: 3",
      File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/distutils/core.py", line 151, in setup
        dist.run_commands()
      File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/distutils/dist.py", line 953, in run_commands
        self.run_command(cmd)
      File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/distutils/dist.py", line 972, in run_command
        cmd_obj.run()
      File "/Users/siddharathgupta/PycharmProjects/CSCI561/Homework1/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/setuptools/command/install.py", line 61, in run
        return orig.install.run(self)
      File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/distutils/command/install.py", line 573, in run
        self.run_command('build')
      File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/distutils/cmd.py", line 326, in run_command
        self.distribution.run_command(command)
      File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/distutils/dist.py", line 972, in run_command
        cmd_obj.run()
      File "/private/var/folders/qh/gdlxnjkx39g723d68_l5dzhc0000gn/T/pip-install-SwC4Jj/libvirt-python/setup.py", line 147, in run
        check_minimum_libvirt_version()
      File "/private/var/folders/qh/gdlxnjkx39g723d68_l5dzhc0000gn/T/pip-install-SwC4Jj/libvirt-python/setup.py", line 40, in check_minimum_libvirt_version
        spawn([get_pkgcfg(),
      File "/private/var/folders/qh/gdlxnjkx39g723d68_l5dzhc0000gn/T/pip-install-SwC4Jj/libvirt-python/setup.py", line 36, in get_pkgcfg
        raise Exception("pkg-config binary is required to compile libvirt-python")
    Exception: pkg-config binary is required to compile libvirt-python

    ----------------------------------------
Command "/Users/siddharathgupta/PycharmProjects/CSCI561/Homework1/venv/bin/python -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='/private/var/folders/qh/gdlxnjkx39g723d68_l5dzhc0000gn/T/pip-install-SwC4Jj/libvirt-python/setup.py';f=getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('\r\n', '\n');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, 'exec'))" install --record /private/var/folders/qh/gdlxnjkx39g723d68_l5dzhc0000gn/T/pip-record-4drvGZ/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile --install-headers /Users/siddharathgupta/PycharmProjects/CSCI561/Homework1/venv/include/site/python2.7/libvirt-python" failed with error code 1 in /private/var/folders/qh/gdlxnjkx39g723d68_l5dzhc0000gn/T/pip-install-SwC4Jj/libvirt-python/
You are using pip version 18.0, however version 18.1 is available.
You should consider upgrading via the 'pip install --upgrade pip' command.
```

I'm using Python 2.7.10

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. For Ubuntu/Debian OS,

   ```
   apt-get install pkg-config
   ```

   For Redhat/Yum OS,

   ```
   yum install -y pkgconfig
   ```

   For MacOS,

   ```
   brew install pkg-config
   ```
2. Install `libvirt`:

   ```
   pip install libvirt-python
   ```

Answer (score 0):

The exception error message shows the problem

```
Exception: pkg-config binary is required to compile libvirt-python
```

The `libvirt-python` module is a binding to the libvirt C library API. In order to compile the C code associated with `libvirt-python`, it needs to find the libvirt library and include files.  For this purpose it uses the `pkg-config` tool which is a widely used standard for locating libraries. You don't appear to have `pkg-config` installed on your host, so you need to install this.  You can probably get it for OS-X from `homebrew` - libvirt itself should be available from there too, if you've not already got it.

Comment: It is already there. I installed it using homebrew

Comment: What is already there ?  libvirt or pkg-config, or both ?  Assuming both are already installed from homebrew, then it could be that your $PATH does not contain the directory where homebrew installed the pkg-config binary.

Comment: pkg-config is already there. I will check $PATH and add the required directory if needed. Thanks for your help.